# How to consider features while forecasting?

Tags: data-science, data-science-experience

I have to forecast future utilisation of my emplyees based on their past data based on zone,slot.

Here zone and slot is the 2 features i wanted to include while forecasting.Any suggestions how to proceed.

data looks as like

```
dt          zone    slot       utilization
--          ----    -----      -----------
2019-06-23  236    1        87.018695

2019-07-07  218    3        37.497308

2019-07-08  218    2        49.132561
```

python is the programming language we are using here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give some more details? You're saying you want to forecast the *utilization* parameter, by using *zone* and *slot* features. Then you proceed to say *zone* and '*hour*'? What is '*hour*'?

To answer your question, this type of problem could be considered a *regression*-problem, since you want to estimate a numerical value '*utilization*'. What language are you working with? For Python, the [*scikit* library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) has some easy to implement regression models.

Also, if you consider your explanatory features *zone* and *slot* to be [categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) features you'd probably need to dummy encode them.